Jasperreport jrxml is leaving extra space on previous page when textfield stretches on to next page in pdf format
I am using below jrxml :
<!-- Created with Jaspersoft Studio version 6.12.0.final using JasperReports Library version 6.12.1-ac0eebdb29e4c0985457bab279a6db744d661530  -->
<jasperReport xmlns="http://jasperreports.sourceforge.net/jasperreports" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:schemaLocation="http://jasperreports.sourceforge.net/jasperreports http://jasperreports.sourceforge.net/xsd/jasperreport.xsd" name="template" pageWidth="595" pageHeight="842" columnWidth="555" leftMargin="20" rightMargin="20" topMargin="20" bottomMargin="20" uuid="3f93d7b8-7bef-45d5-8969-065481b183ed">
    <property name="net.sf.jasperreports.governor.timeout" value="60000"/>
    <property name="ireport.zoom" value="0.90909090909091"/>
    <property name="ireport.x" value="0"/>
    <property name="ireport.y" value="240"/>
    <property name="net.sf.jasperreports.awt.ignore.missing.font" value="true"/>
    <property name="net.sf.jasperreports.pdf.force.linebreak.policy" value="true"/>
    <property name="com.jaspersoft.studio.unit." value="pixel"/>
    <property name="com.jaspersoft.studio.unit.pageHeight" value="pixel"/>
    <property name="com.jaspersoft.studio.unit.pageWidth" value="pixel"/>
    <property name="com.jaspersoft.studio.unit.topMargin" value="pixel"/>
    <property name="com.jaspersoft.studio.unit.bottomMargin" value="pixel"/>
    <property name="com.jaspersoft.studio.unit.leftMargin" value="pixel"/>
    <property name="com.jaspersoft.studio.unit.rightMargin" value="pixel"/>
    <property name="com.jaspersoft.studio.unit.columnWidth" value="pixel"/>
    <property name="com.jaspersoft.studio.unit.columnSpacing" value="pixel"/>
    <style name="text" isDefault="true" fontName="Arial" fontSize="13">
        <box leftPadding="3" rightPadding="3"/>
    </style>
    <detail>
        <band height="58" splitType="Stretch">
            <textField textAdjust="StretchHeight">
                <reportElement positionType="Float" stretchType="RelativeToTallestObject" isPrintRepeatedValues="false" x="0" y="30" width="216" height="20" isRemoveLineWhenBlank="true" isPrintWhenDetailOverflows="true" forecolor="#000000" uuid="cf36fa68-acb1-4d34-9098-610181a6da5e"/>
                <box>
                    <pen lineWidth="0.25"/>
                    <topPen lineWidth="0.25"/>
                    <leftPen lineWidth="0.25"/>
                    <bottomPen lineWidth="0.25"/>
                    <rightPen lineWidth="0.25"/>
                </box>
                <textElement textAlignment="Left" markup="none">
                    <font isBold="true" isItalic="false"/>
                </textElement>
                <textFieldExpression><![CDATA["This concerns activities of world Bank Group entities involving vehicles that could be classified as Covered Funds under the Volcker Rule. Such vehicles could include mutual funds, private equity funds, hedge funds, debt funds, CDOs and CLOs, securitization vehicles, commodity pools, SPVs, structured product vehicles, repackaging vehicles or any other type of investment vehicle or segregated pools of assets (each, a “vehicle”). Please select the applicable fund type for the proposed activitiesThis concerns activities of world Bank Group entities involving vehicles that could be classified as Covered Funds under the Volcker Rule. Such vehicles could include mutual funds, private equity funds, hedge funds, debt funds, CDOs and CLOs, securitization vehicles, commodity pools, SPVs, structured product vehicles, repackaging vehicles or any other type of investment vehicle or segregated pools of assets (each, a “vehicle”). Please select the applicable fund type for the proposed activities.This concerns activities of world Bank Group entities involving vehicles that could be classified as Covered Funds under the Volcker Rule. Such vehicles could include mutual funds, private equity funds, hedge funds, debt funds, CDOs and CLOs, securitization vehicles, commodity pools, SPVs, structured product vehicles, repackaging vehicles or any other type of investment vehicle or segregated pools of assets (each, a “vehicle”). Please select the applicable fund type for the proposed activities.This concerns activities of world Bank Group entities involving vehicles that could be classified as Covered Funds under the "]]></textFieldExpression>
            </textField>
        </band>
    </detail>
</jasperReport>

it gives me report that leaves space in pdf on previous page when textfield stretches out on next page.
Any help would be appreciated.
I tried checking jasper docs but didn't find anything.

Hi Community, I am expecting for help. Please help.
